# passing values in script using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, asp-classic

I think this just my lack of writing in script experience.
I am trying to use ***AJAX*** and **Google Maps marker** to grab the `lat` and `long` from the marker to make a request to a database so I can populate a table below the map.
I seem to be able to grab the `lat` and `long` but I do not seem to be able to pass it to the page making the new request.  I have tested to make sure I am getting the `lat/long` with an alert and I am getting it.

But I cannot seem to find the correct syntax to pass it to the request.

Also I am writing in **Classic ASP**. I would appreciate responses that help me in this language and not suggestions that I move to ASP.NET  I am headed in this direction but for now this is how I am doing it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var j =0; 
  var sites = <%=overallpass%>;

   function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var theicon = sites[5];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4],
            icon: sites[5]
        });

        var contentString = "Some content";

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
            loadXMLDoc(event.latLng) 
        });

    }
  }
</script>
<script>
 function loadXMLDoc(location)
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=location.lat()",true);
   xmlhttp.send();

 }
 </script>
```

The `xmlhtpp.open` statement is where I am trying to pass the `lat/long` to the `demo_get2.asp` file. In this example I have a piece of text that passed properly to `fname`.  But I am trying to pass the `lat` to `lname`.

I have also tried something like this
    "demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=" + location.lat()
but this does not work either.

As a side question. I have been using W3schools as  a source for some code examples. (hence the poor choice in variable names here. I will clean that up)  but in some of their examples the have files listed such as the `demo_get2.asp`. I cannot find where those files are located to see what the code is exactly. In the case above I created my own file that simply reads the two values and displays them on the page. It works.  But for other examples I am interested in seeing what the actually code they have in their examples. I cannot seem to find wqhere they share these.  In the TryIt examples I am not finding it either.

Answer (score 0):

put your variable out of the string and it should be ok ;)

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=" + location.lat(), true);
```

..well now i read the rest of your post ...if this doesnt work also - it might be because you have "()" after name of property "lat" of the object "location".

...no i'm wrong again :) ...it's a method ...and this line really should be working, you need to precise what isn't working in your code. AJAX doesn't send anything? wrong data is being sent / backend ASP file recives wrong data? ...all answers to these questions you should find in console of your browser (press f12 to openit then load/reload your page, make a new marker and check what's wrong by looking at "script", and "network" tabs of the console).

...after your comment - i think i know what is the problem..

try to change your listener to this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", loadXMLDoc));
```

and change the beginning of your function:

```
function loadXMLDoc(e) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  var locationLat = e.latLng.lat();
  var locationLng = e.latLng.lng();
```

now you build your query string like this:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname="+locationLat,true);
```

it should work - it will pass the latitude to your ASP script now.

Comment: I changed the line of code to
       xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=" + location.lat,true);

  and the resulting output was Henry function(){return this[a]}

so I don't think that is quite right yet

Comment: in the original example I gave   the results had the output  for the  of the myDiv element looks like
      Henry location.lat()

I tried your example and showed you the output.  The element myDiv had out put of 
      Henry function(){return this[a]}

I was kind of expecting something like
       Henry 43.2134534

Comment: you didnt notice my edit - i added some lines to the answer above.
I checked the code myself and it works for sure - you should get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although a basic XMLHttp request with JavaScript is perfectly good, I would like to kindly offer you jQuery $.ajax for that sake. Incredibly simple, intuitive and easy to use with Classic ASP.

What you need is to generate a JSON object as a response from the external AJAX page which provides you with the data. Something of that sort (this is "demo_get2.asp"):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
lat = Request.QueryString("lat")
lng = Request.QueryString("lng")
Set lRS = Conn.execute("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable WHERE...")
if not lRS.eof then
    results_fName = lRS("FirstName")
    results_lName = lRS("LastName")
end if
Response.Write("{""fName:"" & "" & results_fName & "",""lName:"" & results_lName & ""}")
Response.End
```

The response of this page will be a JSON string:

```
{ "fName": "John", "lName": "Smith" }
```

Your JavaScript should be something of that sort:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(location) {
    // forming an address with the parameters as query string,
    // note that the query string variable names are correspondent to those 
    // that are read in "demo_get2.asp":
    var address = "demo_get2.asp?lat=" + location.lat() + "&lng=" + location.lng();
    var xhRequest = $.ajax({
        url: address,
        type: "GET",
        data: null, // you can also pass the input as a JSON string instead
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonResult) {
            return jsonResult;
            // This is the JSON object formed by the response of
            // demo_get2.asp
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Something bad just happened: " + error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The jsonResult object returned by the ajax request can be used with the names we gave to the elements within the JSON string in "demo_get2.asp":

```
var firstNameString = jsonResult.fName;
var lastNameString = jsonResult.lName;
```

Hope it helps.